# Disabling display on a div

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to remove display until a var is met, but it isn't working properly, any help?

```
       function test() {
   var x = document.getElementById('trash_01');
   if (trashcan = 0) {
   x.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `trashcan = 0` instead of `trashcan === 0` in your if statement, so it assigns 0 to trashcan instead of checking if it is 0

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: If it fixed your issue, please accept the answer ;)

Comment: the full explanation is `if (trashcan = 0)` first assigns 0 to `trashcan`, and then the result (in this case, always 0) is evaluated for the if condition ... 0 being falsey ... therefore the condition can never be `truthy`

Answer (score 0):

you make the mistake the same as this guy: [Input's placeholder won't change from <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061769/inputs-placeholder-wont-change-from-select,one) '=' means assignment,two or three '=' just means if equal,good luck