# Input's placeholder won't change from <select>

Tags: javascript

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to make the placeholder of the inputs change when I change the select. The first input successfully changes, but that doesn't seem to be the same with the second input. Below is the code that I am using:

```js
function onChange(fromOrTo) {
  if (fromOrTo = 'from') {
    document.getElementById("from").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectFrom").value;
  } else if (fromOrTo = 'to') {
    document.getElementById("to").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectTo").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sect">
    <section>
      <select onchange="onChange('from')" id="selectFrom">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
      <span class="toText">to</span>
      <select onchange="onChange('to')" id="selectTo">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="text" id="from">
      <span id="toText">to</span>
      <input type="text" id="to">
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to compare with === instead of =

```js
function onChange(fromOrTo) {
  if (fromOrTo === 'from') {
    document.getElementById("from").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectFrom").value;
  } else if (fromOrTo === 'to') {
    document.getElementById("to").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectTo").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sect">
    <section>
      <select onchange="onChange('from')" id="selectFrom">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
      <span class="toText">to</span>
      <select onchange="onChange('to')" id="selectTo">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="text" id="from">
      <span id="toText">to</span>
      <input type="text" id="to">
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one equals sign in each of your `if` conditionals. This [**assigns**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) to the variable rather than [**compares**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) it. Switching to two equals signs (or three to avoid type coercison) will resolve this problem:

```js
function onChange(fromOrTo) {
  if (fromOrTo === 'from') {
    document.getElementById("from").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectFrom").value;
  } else if (fromOrTo === 'to') {
    document.getElementById("to").placeholder = document.getElementById("selectTo").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sect">
    <section>
      <select onchange="onChange('from')" id="selectFrom">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
      <span class="toText">to</span>
      <select onchange="onChange('to')" id="selectTo">
        <option value="Celcius">Celcius</option>
        <option value="Farenheit">Farenheit</option>
        <option value="Kelvin">Kelvin</option>
        <option value="Reamur">Reamur</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section>
      <input type="text" id="from">
      <span id="toText">to</span>
      <input type="text" id="to">
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```